# websocket messages a nifi cluster to kafka without duplicates

Tags: websocket, apache-kafka, apache-nifi

In a current project im working on, Im using a one flume server in order to initiate a connection with socket-io websocket that sends events, when consumes the messages it writes them into a kafka topic.
I want to use a nifi cluster with ConnectWebSocket processor in order to consume the messages from the websocket and finally insert them into a kafka topic.
Can nifi cluster lead to a duplicate messages in the topic as a result of more than one broker in the cluster handling the same event?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I checked it, I saw that with the default configurations there will be duplications because all the nodes will perform the same processes.
But there is an option to configure the ConnectWebSocket scheduling to Execute only the primary node and in case it shuts down for some reason, another node will do the work instead.
That solved my problem in order to write events only once in a stable way.